# How Can I Exclude a Visual Studio Project from an Azure Deployment Package?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, mstest, web-deployment

I'm not sure if Visual Studio 2010 already does this or not with respect to how it packages Azure deployments, but I have a Visual Studio solution which contains 5 projects:

1. The Azure Service Project
2. The project for my web role
3. 2 class library projects which
   contain the DAL and BLL that my
   roles use
4. And one MS Test project used for
   unit and integration testing across
   all of these projects

My deployment package right now is roughly 100 mbs, and takes a while to upload. I have some other things I can do to make it smaller, but what I want to know is if there's a way I can make sure that the MS Test project isn't being packaged alongside everything else given that it has the largest footprint. Any suggestions, or is this not actually a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are no references from your web role, the DAL or BAL projects to the test project, then it shouldn't be included in the package.

If you're worried about it I would first of all double check all of the references in the web role, DAL and BLL projects to make sure that you're not accidentally referencing the test project.

As long as that is OK, I'd then do a publish of the project to disk and then have a poke around in the \bin directory if the cloud project to see what's actually using up all of that space.

Answer (score 0):

Just as stated before is you do not have any references to your test project in your web role you should not worry for having it deployed alongside the rest of your code.

Another thing I would recommed is to just precompile your web site and 
add it as another site in your file using a host header for it.
The advantage of that is that you can create a msbuild task to precompiled your site and just upload it.

Also I reposted about a solution for putting your view files in azure storage which will allow you to modify appearance without going thru the republish process.

http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2011/05/01/windows-azure-and-websites-in-a-flux.aspx